# geoNear Callback?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, geolocation, geospatial, coffeescript

I have a collection called test that I want to query with geoNear. The 2d index is set on the field loc.

Am I using db.runCommand correctly here?

```
db.open (err, client) ->
    db.collection 'test', (err, collection) ->
        db.runCommand {geoNear:"loc", near:[50,50], $maxDistance:1}, #callback here? what params?
```

I would normally do something like `.toArray (err, docs) ->` then then use the found docs but how sholud I implement the callback when using geoNear? It already returns an object with meta data right? How do I access it?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use:

db.command(params, callback)